# angularjs ui bootstrap datepicker unexpectedly adding a day

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Good day, by default I set a date in the format like this YYYY-MM-DD in the ui bootstrap datepicker input field using momentjs. The date shows correctly in the format I want it to be. when I select a different date it show correctly the input field but when I decide to console log the value a day is added to it and with a timezone (T00:00:00.000Z).  here is a snippet of my html

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Drawdown Ent. Date <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" 
                           class="form-control" 
                           datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                           ng-model="bookloan.drawdown_ent_date" 
                           is-open="drawdown_ent_date.open" 
                           ng-click="drawdown_ent_date.open = true" 
                           datepicker-options="entDateOptions" 
                           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                           close-text="Close" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

here is a snippit of my JavaScript code:

```
$scope.bookloan.drawdown_ent_date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

What could cause this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: I've created a Plunker, not using moment.js (http://plnkr.co/edit/ZH7SD940lL2TXaUuHdVc?p=preview) and the watcher displays the correct date when the date picker is changed.

Comment: Also, `$scope.dt = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");` gives an error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my problem by using this directive:

```
app.directive('datepickerLocalDate', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: ['ngModel'],
        link: link
    };
    return directive;

    function link(scope, element, attr, ctrls) {
        var ngModelController = ctrls[0];

        // called with a JavaScript Date object when picked from the datepicker
        ngModelController.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            // undo the timezone adjustment we did during the formatting
            viewValue.setMinutes(viewValue.getMinutes() - viewValue.getTimezoneOffset());
            // we just want a local date in ISO format
            return viewValue.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
        });

        // called with a 'yyyy-mm-dd' string to format
        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
            if (!modelValue) {
                return undefined;
            }
            // date constructor will apply timezone deviations from UTC (i.e. if locale is behind UTC 'dt' will be one day behind)
            var dt = new Date(modelValue);
            // 'undo' the timezone offset again (so we end up on the original date again)
            dt.setMinutes(dt.getMinutes() + dt.getTimezoneOffset());
            return dt;
        });
    }
}]);
```

And place directive name in the input element:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Drawdown Ent. Date <span style="color: red;">*</span></label>
                    <input type="text" 
                           class="form-control" 
                           datepicker-local-date
                           datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" 
                           ng-model="bookloan.drawdown_ent_date" 
                           is-open="drawdown_ent_date.open" 
                          ng-click="drawdown_ent_date.open = true" 
                           datepicker-options="entDateOptions" 
                           date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" 
                           close-text="Close" />
                </div>
            </div>
```